# Which part of this code ensures the result is in the range 0.,.m-1?

Tags: c, math

I am new to C and am confused by this hashing code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
// defines uint32/64_t as unsigned 32/64-bit integer.
uint32_t hash(uint32_t x, uint32_t m, uint64_t a, uint64_t b) {
// hashes x strongly universally into the range [m]
// using the random seeds a and b.
return (((a*x+b)>>32)*m)>>32;
}
```

The result is supposed to be in the range 0...m-1 but I don't see how that is ensured.

x and m are 32 bit integers while a and b are uniformly random 64 bit integers.  `(a*x+b)>>32` only uses the 32 least significant bits, so multiplied with the 32-bit integer `m`, we get the exact product in 64 bits with no overflow.   I still don't see why the result is in the range 0..m-1 though.

Comment: By the nature of binary numbers, the `(a*x + b) >> 32` is going to be less than `2^32`. If you think of `2^32` as `1`  in the MSB, then your `(a*x + b)` is less than `1`, and so `*m` gives you a result `<m` in the MSB. You then shift that result into LSB (`>> 32`), so the resultant number must be less than `m`. Note that MSB would be the the "larger" bits.

Comment: @Rogue (Only for the pedantic) "(a*x + b) >> 32 is going to be less than 2^32" assumes that `(a*x + b)` is 64-bit or smaller result (there was no integer promotions).  That is true on machines today.  But, for fun, consider `int/unsigned` is 128-bit, then `(a*x + b) >> 32` could be a 65-bit result.  Avoidable with `((uint64_t)(uint32_t)((a*x+b)>>32)*m)>>32`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica In C, you are either a pedant or a segfault :)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I was going off the fact that the OP is using `uint64_t`, so `(a*x + b)`, even with promotion, would be a `uint64_t` (from my understanding) that is then shifted down. Even with `uint32_t` for `a/b` and `uint16_t` for `x`, you wouldn't get a `uint64_t` from `(a*x + b)`, you'd get an overflow.

Comment: @Rogue If such a 128-bit `unsigned` machine existed, `a*x +b` would be performed with 128-bit math and the 64-bit `a` * 32-bit `x` results in a 96-bit product.  Adding `c` may make 97-bit.  Shifting the 32 ends with a 65-bit result.  Yet since such a machine is most fanciful, its not a real concern.  This exercise though does apply today had we been doing `uint8_t hash_small(uint8_t x, uint8_t m, uint16_t a, uint16_t b)` on a 32-bit machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Briefly

The type of `a*x` is `uint64_t`, so it produces at most a 64-bit result (barring an exotic C implementation with `int` wider than 64 bits). Then `>>32` removes 32 bits, so the result is less than 2<sup>32</sup>. Then multiplying by `m` produces something less than 2<sup>32</sup>•`m`. Then applying `>>32` to that produces something less than 2<sup>32</sup>•`m`/2<sup>32</sup> = `m`.

So the result is less than `m`.

### Fuller

The type of `a` is `uint64_t` and the type of `x` is `uint32_t`. In `a*x`, `x` is converted to `uint64_t`, and the multiplication is performed with `uint64_t`.

The type `uint64_t` can represent values in [0, 2<sup>64</sup>), so the result is in that interval. (“[*a*, *b*)” means the interval includes the endpoint *a* and does not include the endpoint *b*.) If the mathematical result of the multiplication is outside that interval, the computed result equals the mathematical result reduced by subtracting some integer multiple of 2<sup>64</sup>—higher bits are discarded.

Then `b` is added to this. The type of `b` is `uint64_`, so the result is again in [0, 2<sup>64</sup>).

Then `>>32` is applied. This is defined to produce the result of dividing by 2<sup>32</sup> and discarding the fractional part. So the result must be in [0, 2<sup>32</sup>). Equivalently, you can think of it as discarding 32 bits from a 64-bit number (possibly with leading 0 bits), yielding a 32-bit number.

Then we multiply by `m`. Multiplying a number in [0, 2<sup>32</sup>) by `m` produces a number in [0•`m`, 2<sup>32</sup>•`m`). (This result fits in a `uint64_t` because the type of `m` is `uint32_t`, so we are multiplying two 32-bit numbers.)

Finally, `>>32` is applied again. The result is some number in [0•`m`, 2<sup>32</sup>•`m`) divided by 2<sup>32</sup>, with the fractional part discarded. So the result is in [0•`m`/2<sup>32</sup>, 2<sup>32</sup>•`m`/2<sup>32</sup>) = [0, `m`).

Therefore, the result is in [0, `m`). Since the fractional part is discarded, it must be in [0, `m`−1].

Comment: The conclusion is correct, just a tiny comment: Multiplying an integer in [0, 2^32) by m has an upper limit of (2^32-1)*m, so that result is in [0*m, 2^32*m-m] . Assuming m is not 0 and since m can be at most 2^32-1, dividing by 2^32 still gives at most m-1, so as said, the conclusion holds (assuming m is not 0).